# How to access Kiwi-tcms MariaDB on Windows 7 Docker Toolbox?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I need to regularly export Kiwi-tcms data to MongoDB. Kiwi-tcms is installed on my local Windows 7 using Docker Toolbox. I see that Kiwi-tcms stores data in MariaDB, how can I connect to MariaDB? Is there any Kiwi-tcms API that I can use to export data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the commands on this page:
http://kiwitcms.org/blog/atodorov/2018/07/30/how-to-backup-docker-volumes-for-kiwi-tcms/

In particular, I use the dumpdata command a lot on Windows 10 and I end up with a JSON formatted text file with the DB contents.

Answer (score 1):

This is an API, see `tcms-api` package on PyPI. Documentation how to use it is online.